# Changing a multiple file extension using single line command

Tags: find, filenames, xargs, mv

I have some files whose names contain multiple extensions:

```
$ ls -r
File1_345.R.12345
File1_3.234.R.6789
File1_2345.R.2345
File1_12345.R.12345
$
```

I want to rename them
to remove all the existing extensions and replace them with `.txt`. 
Output should be below:

```
$ ls -r
File1_345.txt
File1_3.txt
File1_2345.txt
File1_12345.txt
```

Is it possible to use find and xargs command?

Comment: What happens in the situation of another file named `File1_2345.R.1234`?  Why does the command need to be on a single line?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to remove all extensions (everything after the ***first*** dot)
from each filename, do

```
$ for f in *
do
    mv -- "$f" "${f%%.*}.txt"
done
```

Of course, if you really want to do this in one line,
just collapse the above to

```
$ for f in *; do mv -- "$f" "${f%%.*}.txt"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with GNU Parallel:

```
find ... | parallel mv {} '{=s/\..*//=}'.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task, I would highly recommend using the `rename` tool (e.g. by Larry Wall in Ubuntu):

```
rename --verbose 's/\..*$/.txt/' File*
# replaces everything after the first dot.
```

or with a more specific regex: `'s/\.R\.[0-9]+$/.txt/'`

Comment: Be aware that there are two different commands named `rename` and they don't work the same. One is written in perl, the other is a GNU utility.